# Accessing Microsoft Graph using App Password

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

When an Azure Active Directory (AAD) user enables Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA), the only option to authenticate programs is using "app passwords."

Is it possible to access Microsoft Graph using an App Password? Basic Auth has been generally deprecated, but perhaps there is a way?

Comment: If by access using App Password you mean accessing Microsoft Graph using application identity.. i.e. clientId and clientSecret only as per OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant flow (without any specific user context) then yes it's definitely possible as Microsoft Graph API does work with Application Permissions. Here is a link which explains detailed steps for Azure AD v2.0 https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service and similar things should work for Azure AD v1.0 as well.

Comment: @Marc I meant using the Office App password to side-step the 2FA

Comment: Graph uses OAuth to authenticate against AAD. If 2FA is enabled for that tenant or user, there isn't a simple way around that. You could try using the app password on the auth page but I suspect it won't accept it.

Comment: I’ve tried and app password isn’t accepted at modern login prompt. So I am wondering if there is some squirrels away basic auth option that permits app passwords